# this not working without using strict mode when invoking function from global scope

Tags: javascript, strict

logging "this" logs the contents of the global object but "this.name" logs undefined instead of "kenny". I am using node to execute the script

```
var name = "kenny";

function nameLogger() {
    console.log(this);        //is logging the global object
    console.log(this.name);   //undefined
}

nameLogger();
```

Comment: What are you expecting?  `this` refers to the function scope, in which there's no `name` property.

Comment: Why are you trying to store values in the global scope in Node?

Comment: If I evaluate that code in Node, it logs `kenny` to the console after it logs the global object. The `undefined` you are seeing is the return value of the `nameLogger()` function call.

Comment: @Phix "this" does not refer to the function scope, it refers to the global scope, cause the call to nameLogger() is done from global scope

Comment: @JLRishe yes inside node it is working, but if i store this script in a file say "script.js" and run it using node, "node script.js", then it is logging undefined and i can't think as to why that is happening. I tried on multiple systems, does not work. Please see if you can help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @KennyOmega Ok, in a node script, variables are scoped to the script and not added to the global object. So your issue is not with the behavior of `this`, but with the behavior of `var`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JLRishe thank you, i did not know about that behaviour of node. I was trying to bind the this to the global object and it worked in browser but did not work in node. Once again, thanks for the clarification